A miniseries or two-part movie about a love story between two doctors
Here's all I can remember:
Year: ~ 15 years ago
Language: English or French, maybe both
Genre: Drama, Romance, possibly coming-of-age
Story: It's about 2 doctors (male & female) who fell in love, but the woman's father is a very rich guy (owns a company or something) and he was able to separate them. Years later, they reunite while the man (or possibly both of them) was working with Doctors Without Borders in Africa

It sounds a lot like Only Love from 1998 with Marisa Tomei.

Told in flashback, a successful neurosurgeon (Rob Morrow) is unexpectedly called upon to treat his former fiancee, Silvia, who is dying from a brain tumor. The film then flashes back 15 years to when the couple first met as physicians on an African expedition. Based on the 1997 novel by Erich Segal.

Silvia's father is a very wealthy businessman who wants her to marry another man. This was basically a 2-part mini-series, though many different versions exist. Here's the trailer:




Thank you very much, and wow, how you found this movie? I didn't even think it's the right one for 10 minutes until i realized that "Mathilda May" is lead not "Marisa Tomei"

Indeed, she's Silvia - sorry about that, I usually just specify the most famous names because they're easily recognized. Glad you found it! :)
